# PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, scandir

I want to do a RecursiveDirectoryIterator on a set of folders in a directory, say `./temp` and then list the files in each folder according to the name of the folder.

For example I have the folders `A` and `B`.

In A, I have a list of files say, `1.txt`, `2.php`, `2.pdf`, `3.doc`, `3.pdf`.

In B, I have `1.pdf`, `1.jpg`, `2.png`.

I want my results to be like this:

```
A => List of files in A
B => List of files in B
```

How can this be done?

```
<?php 
$scan_it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./temp"); 
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($scan_it) as $file =>$key) { 
    $filetypes = array("pdf"); 
    $filetype = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    if (in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) { 
        $dlist=basename($file); //sort 
?> 
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php echo substr(dirname($file),11);?>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $file;?>"><?php echo basename($file);?></a>
    </li>
</ul> 
<?php 
    }} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Managed to put this together and it somehow works for me. If you have other options please provide. Thanks

$path='./temp';
$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file=>$mykey) {
        if(is_dir($file)) {

$directory = $file;
$mydir = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveRegexIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::FOLLOW_SYMLINKS), 
// match both pdf file extensions and directories
                '#(?<!/)\.pdf$|^[^\.]*$#i'),true);
    foreach ($mydir as $myfile=>$mykey) {
    $result[] = $myfile.'<br />';

    $filetypes = array("pdf");
    $filetype = pathinfo($myfile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if (in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {


// output all matches substr(dirname($file),11)

?>


    <div><h3<?php echo count($result);?>>
    <span><?php echo  substr(PHP_EOL . $directory . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL,13);?></span></h3></div>

    <?php if (!empty($mydir)) {
    foreach ($mydir as $d) {
    if (strpos($d->getFilename(), '.pdf') !== FALSE) {?>
    <div><ul><li><a href="<?php echo $d;?>"><?php echo basename($d->getPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $d->getFilename() . PHP_EOL);?></a></li></ul></div>
        <?php }
         }

            }
        }
}


        }



}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use a combination of [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to iterate through all subdirectories.

The snippet below will do what you require, although it is limited to only creating an array one array deep... this is to avoid getting into a recursive mess, within an already-confusing-to-procedural-brains small snippet.

```
$array = array();

foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("./temp", 
        RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
    // Note SELF_FIRST, so array keys are in place before values are pushed.

        $subPath = $iterator->getSubPathName();
            if($item->isDir()) {
                // Create a new array key of the current directory name.
                $array[$subPath] = array();
            }
            else {
                // Add a new element to the array of the current file name.
                $array[$subPath][] = $subPath;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is the [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) function. The link shows you the documentation of this function.

Comment: The OP is already aware of the function and this question was tagged as such.

Comment: Was trying to be brief but I need to indicate that there are other subfolders in each of the folders. that was my reason for using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator function