# refresh / clear / redraw page with content from a different location

Tags: php, page-refresh, browser-refresh

I've put together some code to search through a directory and for all the jpg images it finds, display thumbnails and my required iptc and exif info. 
The problem is that I have many, many directories of photos and as it is I need an index.php file for each one. 
My directories are named by month and year; "1401" for January 20014, "1402" for Feb etc. and I have a set of shortcut images for each one called "1401.jpg", "1402.jpg" etc.
so I use this code for users to nagivate to other directories where $shortcut has the values of 1401, 1402 etc:

```
echo("<a href=\" . $path . $shortcut . "\"><img src=\"shortcutimages/" . $shortcut . "\"></a>");
```

I'd love to allow users to navigate in a similar way without needing multiple index.php files.
I would guess the best way is as follows:

On a mouseclick on a link like above, the main php (similar to below) should be re-run, replacing what's currently displayed on the screen but with new value for $dir replaced with something like $dir="../" . $shortcut;
Is this the way to do it? As a newbie I apologise if this is really simple but as it is I can't seem to work it out.

thanks in advance for your help,

Sivadas

```
$dir=".";   // or other folder path of choice!
$jpgcount=0;
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($image = readdir($dh)) !== false)
        {
            if (preg_match("/.jpg/", $image))    // only use .jpg files
            {
                $image=$dir . "/" . $image;
                $exif = exif_read_data($image, 0, true);
                $exif_name = $exif['FILE']['FileName']; 
                if(isset($exif['EXIF']['DateTimeOriginal']))
                {
                    $timestamp = $exif['EXIF']['DateTimeOriginal'];
                }
                    else
                { 
                    $timestamp = "1971:01:01 01:01:01";  // puts in a datestamp if one doesnt exist 
                }
                $datename[] = $timestamp . $exif_name;        // create array of date+name to allow sorting by date then retrieval of date ordered names once datestamp is removed
                $jpgcount++;                    // counts number of jpgs in folder
            }
        }
        sort($datename);                        // sort date+name array by date
        for($c=0; $c<$jpgcount; $c++)
        {
            $image = pythonslice("$datename[$c]","19:");        // function strips off the datestamp (1st 19 characters) to leave the filename (taken from www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php slow at acedsl dot com)
            $image=$dir . "/" . $image;
            $size = getimagesize("$image", $info);
            echo("<tr><td valign=top><A href=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $image) ."> <IMG border=0 src=showthumb.php?image=" . str_replace(' ', '%20', $image) ."></A><td><td valign=top><font size=-1 face=\"Arial Narrow\">"); // get thumbnail and link to full image
            show_metadata($image,$info);                // function to display all required metadata
            echo "</font></td></tr>";
        }
    closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be worth looking into a combination of [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) instead of using an `index.php` file for every single directory.  There's an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20268565/1267140)

Comment: thanks Havelock - I'm thinking more of how to refresh the screen with the information from another directory - as if the user was moving to another php file.