# Get files using file extension only

Tags: php

Any idea how to get my files using only file extension? Eg. (.cfg)

I tried foreach `(glob("*.cfg") as $filename)` but i need to know the path in order to use glob method.

Comment: try [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Comment: You can use `scandir` if your file at the same folder.

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam different folder

Comment: @YanShuangLow has it worked? How did you do?

Comment: @T3H40 Yes it is working but i used a rather weird method

Comment: If it did, you could post a new answer with the code you used, to share the knowledge you earned with future visitors. Also, if you say rather weird, did the given solution cause problems?

Comment: @T3H40 no problem.. the function glob should return all file names but mine only get the last file even though i loop it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bansi, you should

> try [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

The example given there should work for you:

```
$basepath        = "root/directory/for/search";
$start_directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($basepath);
$iterator        = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);
$result          = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/^.+\.cfg$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
```

After you got your results, you can access your file paths in a list just as you entered it via `$basepath`:

```
foreach( iterator_to_array($result) as $file)
{
    echo "config found at: $file[0]";
}
```

You might find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045622/php-recursivedirectoryiterator) useful as well.

A little more background can be found in [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/how-do-i-recursively-scan-directories-with-phps-directoryiterators/).